# How to Combine two select and two where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

Table ONE:

```
StudentId,  StudentName,  School
1           Sam            ABC
```

Table TWO:

```
StudentCity  StudentId
Paris         1
mexico        2
```

Answer should be "Paris" because StudentId is 1

```
select StudentCity 
from TWO
where StudentId = (select StudentId from ONE where StudentName="SAM");
```

Please Suggest me sql query.

Comment: Try an "inner join".

Comment: What's wrong with the query you wrote? Joining is preferable, but your query should work.[

Answer (score 2):

```
select StudentCity from TWO 
inner join ONE on ONE.StudentId = TWO.StudentId
where ONE.StudentName= "SAM"
```